# Spring Converters for generic targets

Tags: java, spring

I'm having a problem with Spring selecting the wrong `Converter` when converting between  path variable and an generic object. If I have two converters, the correct one is selected on my first request, but then it is continually used for subsequent requests.

So given the example below, whichever URL I hit first, works just fine, but then no matter which URL I go to after, the initial converter is used.

```
@Bean
public Converter<String, Optional<ThingOne>> ...

@Bean
public Converter<String, Optional<ThingTwo>> ...


@RequestMapping("/thingone/{thingOneId}")
public void (@PathVariable("thingOneId") @ModelAttribute("thing") Optional<ThingOne> thing) {
...

@RequestMapping("/thingtwo/{thingTwoId}")
public void (@PathVariable("thingTwoId") @ModelAttribute("thing") Optional<ThingTwo> thing) {
...
```

I tried creating a `ConditionalGenericConverter` so that I'd have a chance to check the resolved type, but it seems to do the same thing. Once it finds a converter, it caches that for the future and it never checks again for others.

So my questions are, am I doing this wrong, and is there a better way to do this than to implement a `GenericConverter` that has to handle all String -> Optional conversions?

Comment: Remove the `@ModelAttribute` don't mix `@PathVariable` and `@ModelAttribute` on a single field...

Comment: I just tried it, however it didn't fix it. However I agree it is wrong to have that there, thanks of the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating a TinyType for each.

```
public static class OptionalThingOne extends Optional<ThingOne>{}

public static class OptionalThingTwo extends Optional<ThingTwo>{}
```

You will of course have to re-implement `Optional.of`. Or you could do the following to avoid this...

```
public static class OptionalThingOne extends AtomicReference<Optional<ThingOne>>{}
```

Comment: I don't like the bloat this adds, but I'd rather a solution I don't like to no solution at all. So you'll get my answer vote. Thanks!